# Unable to assign property Name. string expected, got Instance

Tags: lua, roblox

Ive been trying to code a tycoon and every time i try to test it, it says:  **Unable to assign property Name. string expected, got Instance  -  Server - Script:27**

Part of broken code:

```
local WeaponFolder = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild('WeaponsFolder')

local MinPrice = 0
local CheapestPrice = math.huge
local CheapestWeapon = ""
local NextTemplate = {}
local DB = false

for i = 1,#WeaponFolder:GetChildren(),1 do
    for i, Tools in pairs(WeaponFolder:GetChildren()) do
        if not script.Parent.ScrollingFrame:FindFirstChild(Tools.Name) then
            if Tools.Price.Value > MinPrice and Tools.Price.Value < CheapestPrice then
                CheapestPrice = Tools.Price.Value
                CheapestWeapon = Tools.Name
            end
        end
    end
    
    table.insert(NextTemplate, CheapestWeapon)
    MinPrice = CheapestPrice
    CheapestPrice = math.huge
end

for i, Names in pairs(WeaponFolder:GetChildren()) do
    local Template = script.Parent.Template:Clone()
    Template.Parent = script.Parent.ScrollingFrame
    Template.Name = Names
    Template.Visible = true
    Template.ImageButton.Image = WeaponFolder[Names].ImageLabel.Image
    if not DB then
        DB = true
        Template.ImageButton.UIGradient:Destroy()
    end
    
    local ScriptClone = script.Parent.ClickScript:Clone()
    ScriptClone.Parent = Template.ImageButton
end
```

Comment: Then don't assign an instance. I assume it's `Template.Name = Names`, didn't count the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Names is an object, therefore it cannot be assigned to a string, try this instead

```lua
Template.Name = Names.Name
```